# mousemove doesn't fire if pointer lock is on

Tags: javascript, canvas, pointerlock

I'm observing strange behaviour when attempting to add a `mousemove` listener to `document` after requesting a pointer lock.

I've implemented the following, mostly based on documentation from MDN:

```
  var onLockChange = () => {
    env.handlers.onLockChange.forEach(lis => { lis(); });
  };
  document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', onLockChange, false);
  document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', onLockChange, false);
  document.addEventListener('pointerlockerror', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  }, false);
```

...

```
  var updatePosition = (e) => {
    console.log('EVENT!', e);
  };

  env.handlers.onLockChange.push(() => {
    console.log('INVOKED');
    if ( hasPointerLock() ) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', updatePosition, false);
      console.log('Added Listener');
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', updatePosition, false);
      console.log('Removed Listener');
    }
  })

  canvas.onclick = () => {
    if ( ! hasPointerLock() ) {
      canvas.requestPointerLock();
    }
  };
```

I see the console logs exactly as I expect. When I clock on my canvas element, the pointer gets trapped and I see:

```
INVOKED
Added Listener
```

but I never see `EVENT!`.

To make things weirder, if I comment out the call to `document.removeEventListener` I observe that the mousemove event gets captured but only while locking is off.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Google Chrome.

`mousemove` won't fire under the following conditions:
 - Console is open, AND
 - Pointer is locked

Since I had the console open the *entire time* while debugging my code, I thought my code wasn't working.

I spent an hour trying to figure this shit out. Hopefully the next person doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.movementX` and `event.movementY` instead of `clientX`/`clientY`.

Comment: I don't see where I'm using `clientX` and `clientY` in the original question...